# Why does classOf[T] not work in my object?

Tags: scala

I'm bootstrapping myself into Scala and am struggling with why the compiler disallows `classOf[Hello]` in the following source.

```
package example

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object Hello extends Greeting with App {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[Hello])
  logger.info(s"greeting is $greeting")
  println(greeting)
}

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello"
}
```

The compiler complains

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/robert.kuhar/dev/hellosbt/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/robert.kuhar/dev/hellosbt/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:6:48: not found: type Hello
[error]   val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[Hello])
[error]                                                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 17, 2017 1:20:28 PM
```

Hello is a singleton of a class Hello, no?  What does it take to instantiate a logger leveraging the common "Logger Name is Class Name" in my App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can not get type of `object`.

```
scala> object MySingleton
defined object MySingleton

scala> classOf[MySingleton]
<console>:12: error: not found: type MySingleton
       classOf[MySingleton]
               ^
```

Also, note you when you assign singleton to a variable, type you see is `MySingleton.type`

```
scala> object MySingleton { def foo = "bar" }
defined object MySingleton

scala> val x = MySingleton
x: MySingleton.type = MySingleton$@4ffe3d42

scala> x.foo
res3: String = bar
```

**Normally, I create logger in a singleton object, but with reference to the class.**

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class Hello

object Hello extends Greeting with App {

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[Hello])

  logger.info(s"greeting is $greeting")
  println(greeting)

}

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello"
}
```

**Another approach is to get class with method `.getClass`**

```
scala> object MySingleton
defined object MySingleton

scala> MySingleton.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: MySingleton.type] = class MySingleton$
```

### Readings

http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/